# Select range of rows from PostgreSQL table

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to select range or rows from PostgreSQL table. I tried this code:

```
 public List<CustomersObj> list(int firstRow, int rowCount, String sortField, boolean sortAscending) throws SQLException
        {

            String SqlStatement = null;

            if (ds == null)
            {
                throw new SQLException();
            }

            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            if (conn == null)
            {
                throw new SQLException();
            }

            int countrow = firstRow + rowCount;
            String sortDirection = sortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";

// Oracle
    //        SqlStatement = "SELECT A.* "
    //            + " FROM (SELECT B.*, ROWNUM RN "
    //            + " FROM (SELECT Y.COMPONENTSTATSID, Y.NAME, Y.SERIALNUMBER, Y.WEIGHTKG, Y.ZONECAGE, Y.POWERWATT, Y.MANIFACTURECOMPANY, Y.UFORM, "
    //            + " Y.STATUS, Y.LOCATION, Y.HEATEMISIONSBTU, Y.PRODUCTIONENVIRONMENT, Y.STANDARTLIFETIME, Y.OPERATINGHAMIDITYRANGE, "
    //            + " Y.OPERATINGSYSTEM, Y.DATEDEPLOYED, Y.INTERFACETYPE, Y.TYPE, Y.COOLINGCAPACITYBTU, Y.DATEADDED, Y.DESCRIPTION "
    //            + " FROM COMPONENTWEIGHT X, COMPONENTSTATS Y WHERE X.COMPONENTSTATSID = Y.COMPONENTSTATSID AND Y.COMPONENTTYPEID = 3300 "
    //            + " ORDER BY %S %S) B "
    //            + " WHERE ROWNUM <= ?) A "
    //            + " WHERE RN > ?";
// postgresql
            SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ? ";

            String sql = String.format(SqlStatement, sortField, sortDirection);

            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            List<CustomersObj> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

            try
            {
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                boolean committed = false;

                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setInt(1, countrow);
                ps.setInt(2, firstRow);

                resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
                resultList = ProcessorArrayList(resultSet);

                conn.commit();
                committed = true;

            }
            finally
            {
                ps.close();
                conn.close();
            }

            return resultList;
        }
```

But when I use the pagination I get different number or rows. If I use the query from Oracle it's working fine. But when I want to use the query from PostgreSQL I get different result on every paginated page. Can you give some result how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The parameters `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` in PostgreSQL are described in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) as:

> The LIMIT clause consists of two independent sub-clauses:
>
> ```
> LIMIT { count | ALL } OFFSET start
> ```
>
> **count** specifies the maximum number of rows to return, while **start**
>   specifies the number of rows to skip before starting to return rows.
>   When both are specified, **start** rows are skipped before starting to
>   count the **count** rows to be returned.

This means that this line:

```
int countrow = firstRow + rowCount;
```

is probably wrong. The parameter to pass to LIMIT is the actual row count, not the next row.

The second important thing is that in your statement, the question mark for the offset is *first*, and the question mark for the limit is *second*. But you set the parameters like this:

```
            ps.setInt(1, countrow);
            ps.setInt(2, firstRow);
```

The first one is the (bad) "count", and the second one is the "offset". This should be the other way around.

Finally, the `OFFSET` value is the number of rows to skip, not the number of the first row. So if you expect `firstRow` for the first page to be 1, you should use `firstRow - 1` as your offset.

So, you should replace the `setInt` lines with:

```
            ps.setInt(1, firstRow - 1);
            ps.setInt(2, rowCount);
```

Comment: I get org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: OFFSET must not be negative

Comment: @Peter So check if the `firstRow` really starts from 1. If it starts from zero, you don't need to subtract the 1.

Comment: it's 1. For some reason it's not working properly. Next button and back are not working properly.

Comment: That may be a different issue - perhaps the back button is doing what the forward button is supposed to do, or you allow the back button to be used in the first page. You'll have to use a debugger to solve that or at least get enough information for a new question on SO.

Comment: Well, Oracle query it's working fine, but PostgreSQL query is not working well. Looks like the query is the problem.

Comment: Not sure why it would work in Oracle properly - if you pass it the values 1 for the first row and 5 as the number of rows, it seems that it will give you the rows from 2 to 6. So maybe you are passing it 0 and 5 after all. You should check exactly what numbers the button presses are giving you, using a debugger.

Comment: You can see here the full code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325678/rows-are-not-calculated-properly

Answer (score 0):

Let's put together the key sentences

```
 int countrow = firstRow + rowCount;
 SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY %S %S offset ? limit ? ";
 ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
 ps.setInt(1, countrow);
 ps.setInt(2, firstRow);
```

The argument `LIMIT` in PostgreSQL is for specifiying the maximum number of rows to be retrieved, the number of rows per page.

The argument `OFFSET` determines which is the first row to be retrieved.

Let's assume that you want 50 rows per page.

```
  To retrieve the first page -> `LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0` [rows 0 to 49]

  To retrieve the second page -> `LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50` [rows 50 to 99] 

  ...

  To retrieve the nth page -> `LIMIT 50 OFFSET (n - 1)*50`
```

If your `rowCount` contains the total number of rows to retrieve, it must be assigned to `LIMIT` and your `firstRow` to `OFFSET`. And **you can discard variable `countrow` if you use PostgreSQL.**

UPDATE: Just change

```
 ps.setInt(1, firstRow);  // Assign firstRow to OFFSET
 ps.setInt(2, rowCount);  // Assign rowCount to LIMIT
```

I'm afraid that I agree with RealSkeptic: "*if you expect firstRow for the first page to be 1, you should use firstRow - 1 as your offset*."
If you're obtaining a negative number as the first argument, **the only reason is because your are using 0 as the starting row**.

It makes sense if you consider that first row in Oracle has ROWNUM = 1.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns008.htm

Your query valid for Oracle stands that RN > 0 for the first page.

First row in PostgreSQL is obtained with an OFFSET = 0, so ...

```
  YES ->  ps.setInt(1, firstRow);
  NO  ->  ps.setInt(1, firstRow - 1);
```

Comment: Can you give me example how I need to refactor the code because it's not very clear?

Comment: I'm using this code http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html Looks like the problem is the query. It's designed for this query: "SELECT id, name, value FROM mydata ORDER BY %s %s LIMIT ?, ?"; Right now next button is not working fine. After the second page it's not working.

Comment: @PeterPenzov In that page public void pageFirst() {
        page(0);
    }. You said that firstRow in first page was 1.

Comment: Yes. For some reason after page 2 the next button it's not working.